# How do I use bootstrap 5.02 with npm and webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to bundle my webapp with webpack, but the bootstrap code doesn't seem to be importing properly. I've spent hours fiddling.

things aren't working like did before I setup webpack, and I keep getting this error:

This is my error:

[image: pic of chrome output]

my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    'source-map-loader',
                    'babel-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@popperjs/core": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"),
            "bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"),
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

this is my entrypoint: index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SassFormStyle.css">

    <title>Serial Dilution Diagram Generator User Prompts</title>

  </head>
  
  <body id="mainBody">

    <div id="navigation">
      <!-- ... all the other html that defines how the layout looks ...-->
    </div>


    
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="/dist/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

example of some of the imports in index.js:

```
import {Modal, Collapse} from "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js";
import "./SassFormStyle.scss";
import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
import Big from "/node_modules/big.js/big.mjs";
import {is} from "/modules/serialDilutionTable.js"
import {serialDilutionTable} from "/modules/serialDilutionTable.js";
import {mainAlgo} from "/modules/SerialDilutionAlgorithm.js";
import {resetDiagramInnerHtml} from "/modules/svgFunctions.js";
import {unitCheckmarkAdd} from "/modules/diagramToolbar.js";
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Phillip Tellier",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "big.js": "^6.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.6",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm dist/main.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build-prod": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

I'm using Chrome on windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problems so far by reading the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/)!: (summarized below)

the bootstrap script

```
</script>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"></script>
```

imports Popper into my JavaScript like so:

`import * as Popper from "@popperjs/core"`

If try to import it like this, you get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@popperjs/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

To fix this, you can use an importmap to resolve the arbitrary module names to complete paths. If your targeted browsers do not support importmap, you’ll need to use the es-module-shims project. Here’s how it works for Bootstrap and Popper in my case:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es-module-shims@1/dist/es-module-shims.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "@popperjs/core": "/node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "bootstrap": "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"
    }
}
```

Additionally I added
`devtool: 'eval-source-map'`
to my webpack.config.js at the top level of the config object and that the fixed `Devtools failed to load sourcemap` errors